# PAM listfile allow specific user from specific ip

Tags: ip, pam

here is the question related to configure PAM on Linux;
In order to restrict specific remote user to use SSH only from specific ip, I want to use PAM listfile to achieve it.
I use the configuration in /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
auth required pam_listfile.so  item=ruser sense=allow file=/etc/ssh.allow.users onerr=fail
```

then edit the /etc/ssh.allow.users file with content below:

```
tim@10.12.34.230
```

then use ssh tim@targethost from 10.12.34.230, but it isn't work;
who can tell me what the usage of PAM item=ruser ? I guess ruser means remote user,that's  why I configure the user@ip in configuration.

if PAM listfile cannot achieve the goal, are there any other way to do it? BTW, I don't like to use sshd_config since it need to be restart the service.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your question, wanted to comment on it though it is 7 months old.

To restrict a particular user you can add the below lines in sshd_config that will do.

```
Match Address 10.12.34.230 User tim
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /home/tim
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```